# Haskell "concat" list of tuples using only list comprehensions

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

How to change of list of tuples, like

```
[(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]
```

into a normal list, like

```
[5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

via list comprehensions and without `concat`?

I have tried this:

```
[ [y, z] | xs <- [(1,2),(3,4)], y <- fst(xs), z <- snd(xs) ]
```

Comment: Hint: What do you think `y <- fst(xs)` do? `fst(xs)` is not even a list.

Comment: Besides, [don't need to say thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Upvotes and accepting answers (if any) is better.

Comment: For the record: `f = foldr (\(a,b) acc -> a:b:acc) []` adds every element of every couple to the accumulator. `f [(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]`gives: `[5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To flatten any list with a list comprehension, the form is always the same. Take the multiple elements from the source one-at-a-time.

List comprehensions, like functions let you specify and exact pattern of the source, tuple or list.

Your function is not in the form of multiples, one-at-a-time, so correcting it will never give you what you want. It will, at very least require the use of `concat` to concatenate the output.

Here is the form of a flattening list comprehension

```
[ n |(a,b)<-[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)],n <-[a,b]]
```

`a` and `b` are taken one-at-a-time by `n`, to flatten.